# asp.net smtp mail queue

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, queue

does anyone know of a module thats available for asp.net that uses a queue to send email to an smtp server?

the queue being the operative word here.. we need a proper fallback mechanism for storing any messages that can't be sent so that the send can be re-attempted later

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can submit your messages to an IIS SMTP relay server via [the Pickup Folder](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.7.aspx). This is the cheapest, and probably best, outgoing mail queue for ASP.NET.

Otherwise, you'll just need to connect to your SMTP relay server and configure its queue in whatever manner meets your business needs.

Comment: Going back to at least Windows 2000, IIS has had a built-in SMTP server that includes queuing.  It's easy to setup and if your network connection goes offline, everything will buffer in the queue.